# How to convert this camera function to swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, avfoundation

I have this function in Objective-C, and I want convert this to Swift, but some of this syntax confuses me..

```
 // use front/back camera
 - (IBAction)switchCameras:(id)sender
{
 AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition;
if (isUsingFrontFacingCamera)
    desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
else
    desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;

for (AVCaptureDevice *d in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
    if ([d position] == desiredPosition) {
        [[previewLayer session] beginConfiguration];
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:d error:nil];
        for (AVCaptureInput *oldInput in [[previewLayer session] inputs]) {
            [[previewLayer session] removeInput:oldInput];
        }
        [[previewLayer session] addInput:input];
        [[previewLayer session] commitConfiguration];
        break;
    }
}
isUsingFrontFacingCamera = !isUsingFrontFacingCamera;
```

}

I don't know how do this:

```
 AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:d error:nil];
        for (AVCaptureInput *oldInput in [[previewLayer session] inputs]) {
            [[previewLayer session] removeInput:oldInput];
        }
```

I'm tryng:

```
 var devis : NSArray = self.sessionVideo.inputs
    for device: AnyObject in devis{
        sessionVideo.removeInput(device as AVCaptureInput)
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work about the way you tried? Is there an error message?

Comment: My problem is that show new view device on preview layer, but not save into video session record.. Bu I show that the code is correct, becasuse change this preview vieww

Comment: Can you post the entire replacement code? Are you sure you haven't left out any methods that were being called in the Objective-C version, that are not being called in your Swift converted version?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start with the introductory [Swift Book](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fbook%2Fswift-programming-language%2Fid881256329%3Fmt%3D11&ei=ymcZVMLhJND2yQTHpoDgDQ&usg=AFQjCNG3znRomkZrIzCYfiGhG9XjXsPdyg&sig2=JAlv1pKtQ5lX5CxycN7s9A&bvm=bv.75558745,d.aWw) if you're having problems with syntax, before trying to convert existing code. Otherwise you may make inefficient design choices. But, to directly your snippet of code, you'd do this:

```
for oldInput : AnyObject in previewLayer.session.inputs {
    if let captureInput = oldInput as? AVCaptureInput {
        previewLayer.session.removeInput(captureInput)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
if let oldInputs = self.previewLayer?.session.inputs{
  for oldInput in oldInputs{
    self.previewLayer?.session.removeInput(oldInput as AVCaptureInput)
  }
}
```